# android realm : Restoring realm DB from backup file

Tags: android, realm

I'm working on a note app with realm. I'd like to add backup and restore features. So I've been implementing these features as introduced in [this page](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/example-class-to-export-import-a-realm-database-on-android-c429ade2b4ed#.amvufub54). Here is the user scenario.

1. When an user click Backup button, back up default.realm to temp.realm
2. And an user click restore button, replace default.reaml to temp.realm.
3. Reload data and display with new data(replaced default.realm file).

It works well if I restart my application. But I want to refresh new data immediately. If I did not restart my application, it works weird. So my question is how can i reload restored realm db so that display restored data without application restarting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very important that before copying the `temp.realm` to `default.realm`, all opened Realm instances referring to the old `default.realm` need to be closed. Since those instances still hold a file descriptor to it, and the newly opened Realm instances after copying will hold a different file descriptor and Realm still think they are them same Realm since the path is exactly the same. This is a situation Realm cannot handle, and some strange things could happen.

You can call `Realm.deleteRealm()` to delete the old `default.realm` first. That API will throw if there is any other Realm instance to the realm file which is going to be deleted opened.

Comment: I solved this issue. Your answer was really helpful. I found every code that opening realm instance and closed them. After that, It works well. Thanks~!!!  :)

Comment: lee jeongmin , could you share to me how to configure for restore realm db in Android. I had big issues for restore db from backup file in Android realm db.